# In Solr, how can I make a field 'required' if another field has a certain value?

Tags: solr

My schema has three fields document_type, type_a_description, and type_b_description.

If the value of the document_type field is 'a', then I want the type_a_description to be required. If the value of the document_type field is 'b', then I want the type_b_description to be required, i.e. the equivalent of required="true" in schema.xml.

However, I'm not sure how to implement this in Solr. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to setup a chain of [UpdateRequestProcessors](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateRequestProcessor) to clone the field and then regex replace it into final value. Or a custom (possibly scripting) URP that does whatever you want.

You can see [the full list of UpdateRequestProcessors](http://www.solr-start.com/info/update-request-processors/) on solr-start.com

Comment: Sounds horribly complex. To re-itterate, I just want to make b mandatory if a has a certain value. I don't specify the value of b based on a, only that b is now mandatory if a = 'yes', for example.

Comment: Perhaps your question is not clear, then. What does it actually mean to be mandatory? The document will not get inserted into Solr if it has one but not other? Or you do not find it under some circumstances? Try updating the main question with an expanded description.